# Hide irrelevant focusable elements from screen reader

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an element on page my which overflows horizontally and uses `overflow: auto` to allow content to be scrolled into view. All the content is rendered on load (i.e. it is always present in the DOM, not rendered when scrolled into view).

There are also two custom buttons on the page which use JavaScript to scroll this element to the left and right.

I need the buttons to be clickable for mouse users and focusable for keyboard users. But for screen reader users these buttons really serve no purpose because the fact that the element scrolls is irrelevant to a screen reader which will announce all of the content anyway.

I tried putting `aria-hidden` on the buttons container but this fails the accessibility rule `aria-hidden-focus` (see https://accessibilityinsights.io/info-examples/web/aria-hidden-focus/) because the buttons remain focusable.

I am aiming to achieve the best experience for all users which for screen readers means hiding the buttons which serve no purpose. But I can't work out a way to do this without using JavaScript to try and detect screen readers which seems a bit gross and error prone.

Is there a way this can be solved whilst providing a good experience all round?

Comment: This seems like more of a UX design question more than anything else so maybe [this sister site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) (which I've never used) is better? My personal opinion is not to have the buttons at all - keyboard users can scroll (including left and right) with the arrow keys so I don't see what purpose they really serve. But I'm a front-end developer rather than a designer, even if the fields do overlap somewhat.

Comment: I would recommend using `aria-label` attributes on the buttons to explicitly tell the user that this controls the scrolling. From there the user will be able decide for themselfs what to do next.

Comment: (this assumes you have [focusable content somewhere in that scrollable area](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.5/scrollable-region-focusable). Horizontal scrolling is generally a bad user experience anyway - are you sure you can't avoid that? large tables on small mobile devices are about the only genuine use case I know for horizontal scrolling, although doubtless there may be a few others.)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier a descriptive label is certainly necessary if the buttons really can't be avoided, but I'd assumed the OP already had this. In any case using a separate `aria-label` seems like an anti-pattern as the button's text content (which is what becomes the button's accessible name in the absence of an explicit ARIA label) should be just as descriptive. The visual label should always match the accessible name except in rare cases as otherwise eg voice recognition users are likely to have difficulties.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Without seeing the actual HTML of OP we can't be sure. Not all buttons have text as content. Some might have icons or just colors. I am not seeing the anti-pattern. Aria labels could help in giving more specific instructions for people with screen readers where others without would understand the intent by looking at visual cues or context. I do agree on that the visual label should match the aria label and be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't put aria-hidden=true on a focusable element, for the very simple reason that there is a contradiction:

- When an element is focused, the screen reader must say something, so that the user knows what is under focus now
- The aria-hidden attribute tells the screen reader that this element is irrelevant and should be totally ignored

The first rule is generally stronger than the second because it doesn't make sense at all to say absolutely nothing when the element is focused. Thus the aria-hidden=true is probably going to be partially or totally ignored.
For example, the element can be correctly announced when focused, but may not be announced at all because of aria-hidden=true when reading the page in virtual cursor / browse mode. The result for the user is confusion, since sometimes the element appears to be present, and sometimes it isn't.

So, aria-hidden=true and non-focusability always go together. It's always whether both, or none.

However, beyond the pure technical explanation, it makes in fact no sense to have a focusable element ignored by screen readers, if you consider that blind people aren't alone to use them.
Screen readers are also used by partially sighted, as well as dyslexic people for example.

Someone may have enough vision to have an usefulness for your scrolling thing, but not enough to read text on screen or using a mouse comfortably.
A person with dyslexia, a normal vision, but using the keyboard for whatever reason (there exists a lot), may use a screen reader because reading text on screen is so uncomfortable or exhausting.

So, to wrap up, you have two possible options:

- Hide the element to screen readers and make it non focusable, i.e.  aria-hidden=true + tabindex=-1
- Keep the element focusable and visible for screen readers, i.e. add tabindex=0 if the element isn't already naturally focusable

If you really think that your thing is only useful for mouse and touch users as well as those using another direct pointing device, but absolutely not for keyboard and screen reader users, go ahead for the first option.
In any other case, doing so will lessen accessibility for some users, and you should stay with the second option.

Comment: Imagine you are truncating text like "lorum ipsum..." and then display a button which expands and contracts the hidden text. If you use `line-clamp` or `ellipsis` then a screen reader would read out the entire text whereas in the browser only a section of the text would be shown.

In this case I would argue that it would make sense to hide the focusable button from screen readers.

Answer (score 3):

I believe clearing up one common misconception will render the solution very clear.

**About 22 % of screen reader users are sighted, but have low vision**

– [Screen Reader User Survey #9 Results, Disability](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#disability)

The common misunderstanding when starting with accessibility, is that screen readers would only be used by blind persons, and that therefore you could treat visual UI different to screen reader UI.

That is not the case, hence the rule *aria-hidden-focus*, and [WCAG Criterion 2.5.3 Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html)